# Changing certain attributes and creating a new field for combined data

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, overlapping-features, regular-expression

I have this combined dataset with building heights divided up over several columns ''Height'' ''Building_h'' and ''Building_L. My end goal is to combine them all in one new column. There are however, several problems:

1. All columns are strings. I am aware of the `to_real()` function, but it doesn't work as some of the values have 'm' behind it to indicate that they are in meters. How can I change them?
2. I already used `regexp_replace( "height" , 'm.*', ' ')`  in the field calculator to get rid of the 'm' behind meters and got those into a new field called 'without M', but now only the cases that had m are in this field. They are also still in the field they were originally in, so I still cannot apply the `to_real()`.
3. I want to use with ''WithoutM'' field to add all the other values to as well.

How do I do this?

4. Then there is ''Building_l'' which has the number of levels per building. And so, this is a different way of expressing building height than ''height'' and ''building_h'' do. If I say, for example that an average building level is 3 meters; is there a way I can multiply the value for ''building_l'' by 3 and also put this into the ''withoutM'' field?
5. Last problem is related to the fact that several buildings have a value in more than one column. For example in ''height'' and ''building_l'', how should I handle this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use field calculator.

- Open field calculator.
- Select update existing field, select your target field ("withoutM").
- Go to Function editor, select new file and name your new function.
- On the right side type in this code:

> > ```
> > from qgis.core import *
> > from qgis.gui import *
> >
> > @qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
> >
> > def my_copy(value1, value2, feature, parent):
> >   value2 = value2.replace("m", "")
> >   num_value2 = float(value2)
> >   if num_value1 != NULL:
> >       pass
> >   else:
> >       return float(num_value2)
> > ```

For field with number of levels change else statement to:

> > ```
> >   else:
> >       return float(num_value2) * 3
> > ```

- Click load and go back on Expresion tab.
- Type in: my_copy("your_destination_field", "your_source_field") In
  your case you would replace "your_destination_field" with "withoutM".

This code will check if your destination field is empty, in that case it will copy value from source field.

- Run this for each of your source fields except where you have number
  of levels. For that you just change last line of code to :

  return value2 * 3

..for 3 m high floors..

Maybe not the smoothest solution but I think it should work.

Comment: You can also deal with "m" situation with this code by adding this line above if statement: value2 = value2.replace("m", "").

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have tried your approach and I think it works in theory. There is just a couple of problems: Firstly; when doing the approach for ''building_l'' a 'NULL' Value is returned. I think this is because the attribute of building level is still a string? How do I change this? The second problem comes with overwriting; when the approach works for values from ''height'' (still strings though) that have meters behind them, when will get changed back into  'NULL' when running my_copy("withoutM", "height"). Looking forward to hearing more!

Comment: I changed code in the answer, hope it works now.

Comment: Ah I see. I got rid of the m's now in the ''height field'', but still they are strings, and they don't want to change into integers with to_real(''height''). I also don't get an error message though. As for the steps you outlined, I don't get values in ''withoutM'' yet...  I'm not sure were the bug is; can you maybe explain what ''feature'' and ''parents'' do in: def my_copy(value1, value2, feature, parent)? Maybe I can make sense of it then ;-)

Comment: Lets try simpler way. Choose update "without M" field (that field is real numbers, right?)
In expressions tab: 
If("without M" is NULL,"height", pass)
So, if field without M is empty, fill it with value from "height" else do nothing. After you ran this:
If("without M" is NULL,"building_h", pass)
and finally:
If("without M" is NULL,"Building_l" * 3, pass)

Comment: Yes, that's right it's an Interger64. Unfortunately, this still does not work. What happens is that once a value gets in, it will be reset to NULL with the an If("without M" is NULL,"building_h", pass) statement, no matter what's in the spot of ''building_h'' .

Comment: Running out of ideas then. I tried to simulate your data and it worked for me in this latest way. I should have your data to try work on it for any further help.. If you are handy with Excel you can try select all features in qgis, use ctrl+c, paste it in Excel, use formula to populate empty cells, select all and in qgis use edit -> paste as temporary layer..